# How to disable suhosin.log?

Tags: php, suhosin

In phpmyadmin it says...

"suhosin.log.* should not include SQL, otherwise you get big slowdown"

How do I totally disable suhosin.log in php.ini?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini

You can find that path with phpinfo();

Look for "Additional ini files parsed" in phpinfo() output.